# How to delete Azure Storage Account with a HTTP triggered Azure Function

Tags: c#, azure, azure-storage, azure-functions

Having trouble deleting a storage account with an azure function. If anybody could lead me the right way it would be greatly appreciated

Expected result:
When I make a POST request to my Azure Function, then my Azure Function should delete a Storage Account in a different Resource group

**Edit: This is what I have so far, after Peter Pan's help:**

```
#r "Newtonsoft.Json"

using System.Net;
using Microsoft.AspNetCore.Mvc;
using Microsoft.Extensions.Primitives;
using Newtonsoft.Json;
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Configuration;
using System.Globalization;
using System.Linq;
using System.Net.Http;
using System.Net.Http.Headers;
using System.Security.Claims;
using System.Threading;
using System.Threading.Tasks;
using System.Web;
using Microsoft.IdentityModel.Clients.ActiveDirectory;



public static async Task<IActionResult> Run(HttpRequest req, ILogger log)
{
    log.LogInformation("C# HTTP trigger function processed a request.");

  //  string requestBody = await new StreamReader(req.Body).ReadToEndAsync();
  //  dynamic data = JsonConvert.DeserializeObject(requestBody);

    // performing something with Json here
     // ...

AuthenticationResult result = null;
//.... codes for getting access token
AuthenticationContext authContext = new AuthenticationContext(authority);
ClientCredential clientCredential = new ClientCredential("xxxx-xxxx-xxxx-xxxx-xxxx", "xxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxx/=");
result = await authContext.AcquireTokenAsync("/subscriptions/xxxxx/resourceGroups/xxxx", clientCredential);

var client = new HttpClient();
client.BaseAddress = new Uri("https://management.azure.com/");
client.DefaultRequestHeaders.Add("Authorization", "Bearer "+result.AccessToken);
var resp = client.DeleteAsync("subscriptions/xxxxxxx/resourceGroups/xxxxxx/providers/Microsoft.Storage/storageAccounts/xxxxxxxxxx?api-version=2018-11-01");
return resp.StatusCode.Equals("200") ? new OkResult() : new NotFoundResult();

}
```

**Error being returned:**

```
2019-04-13T10:23:51.234 [Error] run.csx(18,17): error CS0234: The type or namespace name 'IdentityModel' does not exist in the namespace 'Microsoft' (are you missing an assembly reference?)
2019-04-13T10:23:51.412 [Error] run.csx(32,1): error CS0246: The type or namespace name 'AuthenticationResult' could not be found (are you missing a using directive or an assembly reference?)
2019-04-13T10:23:51.454 [Error] run.csx(34,1): error CS0246: The type or namespace name 'AuthenticationContext' could not be found (are you missing a using directive or an assembly reference?)
2019-04-13T10:23:51.514 [Error] run.csx(34,41): error CS0246: The type or namespace name 'AuthenticationContext' could not be found (are you missing a using directive or an assembly reference?)
2019-04-13T10:23:51.556 [Error] run.csx(34,63): error CS0103: The name 'authority' does not exist in the current context
```

Comment: what error are you receiving ? if possible post the code (without the azure storage credentials) so that more users can provide solutions.

Comment: Can you post your code ? error if any

Comment: I am not seeing any errors. The request succeeds but nothing happens. Sorry I am not home now and do not have access to the code but its basically a httpClient that does a .DeleteAsync() to the Azure Storage API to delete it - Thats it

Comment: have added the code block I got

Comment: Are you sure you are receiving a 200 status code back?  Since you are not showing it in code, it's unclear if your httpClient request is including the required Authorization token. Are you including the required auth to actually have permission to do the delete?

Comment: @BryanLewis it's returning 200 yes, no I am not including any auth headers

Comment: Ps. what i've included is all I have at the moment

Comment: I don't see how it could succeed if you are not authenticating.  You should try reviewing the steps here: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/rest/api/azure/  Or bypass the pure REST interface and use the .Net SDK if the function you require is supported (I've never tried deleting a SA with the SDK, so I don't know if that's supported).

Comment: thanks @BryanLewis would you happen to have a link to the SDK documentation?

Comment: I would look at: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/overview/azure/storage?view=azure-dotnet and an example of deleting a storage account at: https://github.com/Azure/azure-libraries-for-net/blob/master/Samples/Storage/ManageStorageAccountAsync.cs

Answer (score 0):

It sounds like you want to use the REST API [`Storage Accounts - Delete`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/rest/api/storagerp/storageaccounts/delete) to delete a Storage Account in Azure Function with Http Trigger, but there is missing some codes to add the header `Authorization` into your http delete request.

The request of `Storage Accounts - Delete` REST API should be like below.

```
DELETE https://management.azure.com/subscriptions/{subscriptionId}/resourceGroups/{resourceGroupName}/providers/Microsoft.Storage/storageAccounts/{storageAccountName}?api-version=2018-11-01
Authorization: Bearer <accessToken got from Azure AD by your web client as the code `result.AccessToken` below>
```

The code to call the api above should be as below.

```
AuthenticationResult result = null;
//.... codes for getting access token
AuthenticationContext authContext = new AuthenticationContext(authority);
ClientCredential clientCredential = new ClientCredential(clientId, appKey);
result = await authContext.AcquireTokenAsync(todoListResourceId, clientCredential);

var client = new HttpClient();
client.BaseAddress = new Uri("https://management.azure.com/")
client.DefaultRequestHeaders.Add("Authorization", "Bearer "+result.AccessToken);
var resp = client.DeleteAsync("subscriptions/{subscriptionId}/resourceGroups/{resourceGroupName}/providers/Microsoft.Storage/storageAccounts/{storageAccountName}?api-version=2018-11-01")
return resp.StatusCode.Equals("200") ? new OkResult() : new NotFoundResult();
```

You can refer to the source code [`TodoListController.cs`](https://github.com/Azure-Samples/active-directory-dotnet-webapp-webapi-oauth2-appidentity/blob/178321d22c457a324167f6d7d0641fa0b1ad5798/TodoListWebApp/Controllers/TodoListController.cs) of the code sample [`Azure-Samples/active-directory-dotnet-webapp-webapi-oauth2-appidentity`](https://github.com/Azure-Samples/active-directory-dotnet-webapp-webapi-oauth2-appidentity) to know more details about how to get the access token from Azure AD by your registered web client. And for more details about client register in Azure AD, you can follow the offical document [`Azure REST API Reference`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/rest/api/azure/) to do it and grant the necessary permission or role on Azure portal.

Comment: Hi Peter, thanks so much for your reply just got to view it now. I am struggling to run it, it is complaining about namespaces not existing even though they do exist, as well as the need for implicit casting of return status code. Error, with updated code will be under my original post

Comment: Managed to correct some of the errors, but the USING ones are still remaining don't understand how, as I am using the ones from Microsoft's documentation

Comment: Am correct in understanding that I need to import NuGet packages for the missing USING references @Peter Pan